# Event loop is in the same thread as Node.js main?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

So Node.js uses event loop for non-blocking IO.

I wonder if that event loop is in the same thread as Node.js main for handling requests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its in the same thread. There will be only one thread for a single node.